# How can a LAN admin enforce YouTube Restricted Mode on their network?

Tags: networking, lan, youtube

I’m confused. How does a LAN administrator change an application setting, in this case YouTube Restricted Mode, on every device in the LAN? The LAN admin does not have physical access to these devices at all. If they have so much application level control, what other applications can they manipulate on the hosts connected to the LAN? This happens when using YouTube in the iOS YouTube app.

Comment: What is the exact URL to reproduce the problem and which browser did you use? Also please post a screenshot. A [German user](https://forum.mods.de/bb/thread.php?TID=217058&page=6) mentioned this happens to him **at home** and the cause was a Firefox addon - i had a blocked YouTube video once at work, but can not reproduce. Please try in a private browser window and also in [Firefox safe mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_Mode) to disable problematic addons.